# How to specify more than 1 value for the value in datatrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

if for example if we want to specify more than one value for the property in data trigger , how to do that

Comment: What have you tried?  What exactly is the use case, explaining this may lead to alternative ways of achieving the same thing.  Have you attempted this and run into difficulties, showing code and errors you've encountered makes your question much easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a MultiDataTrigger -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx
check the sample